# Passing arguments to a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I have a `.bat` file which does some stuff with the variables inside it. I have noticed a strange problem.

At the bottom of that file I have that line:

```
START _mz3_creator.bat %book_name%,%pg_count%,%pg_width%,%pg_height%,%pg_format%,%scale%,%jpg_q_l%,%jpg_q_h%,%res_px_l%,%res_px_h%,%book_type%,%zoomminscale%,%zoommaxscale%,%zoomsnap%,%zoomsteps%,%zoominit%,%maxloaded%,%pagethickness%,%maxthickness%,%thumbscale%,%logo_pos%,%settings%,%plugin_list%,%qualitycontrol%,%centercovers%,%cornerhint%,%pageoffset%,%dragrange%,%searchmethod%,%shadows%,%searchclear%,%startpage%,%version_name%,%make_pg%,%parameter_list%,%thumbloadtext%,%custom_webaddress%,%bookmark_title%,%make_what%,%logo_width%,%logo_height%,%page_type%,%side_bar%,%lang_list%,%hi_res_type%,%language%,%gallery_active%, %bookmark_type%,%thumbloadtextsize%,%elementsfadein%,%thumbs_fetch%, %bgcolor%
```

(I pass 52 arguments for that file)

For now everything works, that `_mz3_creator.bat` file executes fine and it does its job.

But, I was wondering what values have these variables, so I used

```
ECHO START _mz3_creator.bat %book_name%, .......... etc
```

and here's the problem - after I used the `ECHO` command I copied the output:

```
START _mz3_creator.bat "quick",14,816,1056,US,ž,40,90,36,96,pdf,0.25,4.0,"0.25,0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0",2,0,32,0.2,40,0.25,"pw-w,ph-h-60","true, false, false, false, false","options,zoom",true,true,false,0,30,client,0.3,false,1,"pdf",y,"ž","please wait","http://stackoverflow.com",n,m,165,45,b,n,"ž",jpg,en,0,"u",12,false,0,"ž"
```

and pasted it to a blank `.bat` file, and after execution I see some errors.

Why ?

I suppose there is something wrong with the variables formatting after I've copied them. Any ideas ?

### EDIT

inside my original .bat file I see that line

```
SET scale=0
...
SET scale="%scale%"
SET scale=%scale:"=%
IF §%scale%==§ SET scale=§
IF %scale%==0 SET scale=§
```

and then in the output I see `ž` instead of `§`. I think it is treated as `NULL` value

Comment: OK, but in the original file they are separated by commas and it's working

Comment: @Joey - space, tab, comma, semicolon, equal: the CMD parser doesn't care. They all work as parameter delimiters.

Comment: dbenham, ok. You dissected that way more than I did :)

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me. I think I don't understand what your problem is (specially when you said "For now everything works, that `_mz3_creator.bat` file executes fine and it does its job".

Independently of that, I think there are a couple points you should pay attention:

- The parameters of a Batch file are used to execute the file with different *unknown* values, or with values that needs to be separated from those of the original calling file. I suppose that `_mz3_creator.bat` have a hard job to extract those 52 parameters (perhaps in a complex loop with `shift` commands?). You must be aware that when `_mz3_creator.bat` starts, it have access to the same 52 variables and values of the calling program, so all this job is entirely unnecessary (at least, from my point of view).
- Start command is used when a separate execution thread is needed. I don't know if this is the case; otherwise the `start` command is unnecessary (a `call` command would be enough).
- If you want to avoid that `_mz3_creator.bat` modify variable values that must remain the same in the calling program, just insert a `setlocal` command at beginning.

I hope it helps.

Antonio